# Part-of-speech tagger in PHP?

Tags: php, nlp, part-of-speech

I am looking for a simple part-of-speech library or code that I can download. My criteria is that it must be simple to use and free is possible.

Do you know such a library ?

Comment: What are your motivations for down-voting ?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I am guessing it's because this is not a programming question.

Comment: There are a lot of such questions on SO. Is there any thread on meta where this is discussed ?

Comment: what language do you plan to be tagging? do you require a particular tag set or is anything fine as long as basic categories are distinguished?

Comment: @Daan I just need basic categories

Answer (score 8):

There's an implementation of the Brill tagger in PHP:
[How to impliment a Part-of-Speech (POS) tagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751104/how-to-impliment-a-part-of-speech-pos-tagger)
and http://phpir.com/part-of-speech-tagging

You'll probably find more if you Google for "PHP POS tagger". I also have a rudimentary PHP wrapper for the Stanford POS tagger (which runs in Java), which I would be happy to open-source, but as it takes up to five seconds to load the model, you may want to use one of the tools linked to above if real-time processing is your goal. (You only need to load the model once per session, though.)

Comment: I would be interested in your wrapper even if it is not for real-time processing. Do you use github?